# Function text appearing in text field

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am following an Angular tutorial and have come across a strange issue on the registration page.

The confirm control has a value when the page loads:

[image: Password confirm value password]

If I change the type to text I can see what is appearing in there:

[image: Password confirm value text]

This is my component html:

```
<h1 class="page-header">Registration Page</h1>

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onRegisterSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.username.errors && form.controls.username.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.username.errors}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Username" formControlName="username" />
            <ul class="invalid-feedback">
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.required && form.controls.username.dirty">This field is required</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.minlength && form.controls.username.dirty">Minimum length: 3</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.maxlength && form.controls.username.dirty">Maximum length: 15</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.username.errors?.validateUsername && form.controls.username.dirty">Username can contain only letters and numbers</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.email.errors && form.controls.email.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.email.errors}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Email" formControlName="email" />
            <ul class="invalid-feedback">
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.required && form.controls.email.dirty">This field is required</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.minlength && form.controls.email.dirty">Minimum length: 6</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.maxlength && form.controls.email.dirty">Maximum length: 254</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.email.errors?.validateEmail && form.controls.email.dirty">Invalid email format</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.password.errors && form.controls.password.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.password.errors}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Password" formControlName="password" />
            <ul class="invalid-feedback">
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.required && form.controls.password.dirty">This field is required</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.minlength && form.controls.password.dirty">Passwords must be at least 8 characters</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.password.errors?.validatePassword && form.controls.password.dirty">Password must contain at two of the following: uppercase letter, lowercase letters, and numbers</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label>
        <div>
            <input type="password" name="confirmp" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': (form.controls.confirmp.errors && form.controls.confirmp.dirty) || (form.errors?.matchingPasswords && form.controls.confirmp.dirty), 'is-valid': !form.controls.confirmp.errors}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="*Confirm Password" formControlName="confirmp" />
            <ul class="invalid-feedback">
                <li *ngIf="form.controls.confirmp.errors?.required && form.controls.confirmp.dirty">This field is required</li>
                <li *ngIf="form.errors?.matchingPasswords && form.controls.confirmp.dirty">Passwords do not match</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" />
</form>
```

And this is my register component typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { 
    this.createForm();
  }  

  form: FormGroup;

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['',Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(6),
        Validators.maxLength(254),
        this.validateEmail
      ])],
      username: ['',Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(15),
        this.validateUsername

      ])],
      password: ['',Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        this.validatePassword
      ])],
      confirmp: [Validators.required]
    }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'confirmp')})
  }

  validateEmail(controls){
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
    if (regExp.test(controls.value)) {
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return {'validateEmail' : true};
    }
  }

  validateUsername(controls){
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
    if (regExp.test(controls.value)){
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return {'validateUsername': true};
    }
  }

  validatePassword(controls){
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^(((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]))|((?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])))(?=.{8,})/);
    if (regExp.test(controls.value)){
      return null;
    }
    else {
      return {'validatePassword': true};
    }
  }

  matchingPasswords(password, confirmp){
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      if (group.controls[password].value == group.controls[confirmp].value){
        return null;
      }
      else {
        return {'matchingPasswords': true};
      }
    }
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    console.log('Form submitted');
  }



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I have tried to debug how this value is appearing but I can't seem to find the event/code that is causing it.
If I change the `formControlName` value for the confirmation input then the problem disappears so this seems to narrow it down to the typescript doing something with the form.

Can anyone spot where this is coming from?

Comment: You forgot to declare initial value here `confirmp: [Validators.required]`. Indeed `Validator.required` is initial value here. Try `confirmp: ['', Validators.required]`

Comment: @yurzui That was it, good spot, post as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `FormGroup` through `FormBuilder` and use array to declare property you should know that the first item in array is [the value of control](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ba479977159e974bc5093c514f1a05cca9e87618/packages/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L89):

```
_createControl(controlConfig: any): AbstractControl {
  if (controlConfig instanceof FormControl || controlConfig instanceof FormGroup ||
      controlConfig instanceof FormArray) {
    return controlConfig;  
  } else if (Array.isArray(controlConfig)) {
    const value = controlConfig[0];
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  look at this
    const validator: ValidatorFn = controlConfig.length > 1 ? controlConfig[1] : null;
    const asyncValidator: AsyncValidatorFn = controlConfig.length > 2 ? 
                           controlConfig[2] : null;
    return this.control(value, validator, asyncValidator); 
  } else {
    return this.control(controlConfig);
  }
 }
```

If we take a look at your code:

```
confirmp: [Validators.required]
```

we can conclude that `Validators.required` will be value of `confirmp` control.

To fix it simply add value before validator:

```
confirmp: ['', Validators.required]
```

so that your control will have `''` as default value.